# What is this hole in my porch called?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for these types of holes built into the stone wall of this front porch?

[image]

My particular house was built about 100 years ago and it has one.  The above image is of a more modern home design. [Front-Porch-Ideas-and-More.com](https://www.front-porch-ideas-and-more.com/south-pasadena-california.html)

Side question:  I am also wondering if someone could tell me what it is for -- is it purely aesthetics?

---

Here are a few photos of the ___________ in the wall of my front porch.

[image: From the yard]

[image: From the porch]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided it is open at the bottom *and* top, it's a combination '**access to the crawl space**' and '**porch drainage**'.

I have done a number of searches based on '[Craftsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Craftsman) porch design', and I cannot find a special name for it.

It appears to be a classic field stone arch. Most of these homes have a latticed skirting  covering the access to the [crawlspace](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=crawalspace%20mean). They provide ventilation to the underparts of the porch, which unless airy, can become a dark and dank snake and rodent haven. When dry, our canine companions find  it a cool place to take a snooze, especially  during the dog days of summer*.

---

*I seem to recall a Michael J Fox movie filmed in Georgia, and a sweat-gland-less family that sleep beneath their porch during the hot nights.

---

Update:

[Phil Sweet](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/160746/phil-sweet) has suggested 'scupper', and I thought that was only nautical, however,

> an outlet in the side of a building for draining water.

[Lexico](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=scupper)

Given the position of the outlets, they appear to be drains; [in other words 'scuppers'.](https://www.copper.org/applications/architecture/arch_dhb/arch-details/gutters_downspouts/scuppers.html)

***Scuppers*** would be the best suggestion.

Comment: Not just drainage, but ventilation. You don’t want damp stagnant air trapped in a dark space.

Comment: fieldstone is one word.  Yes, therefore, the arch is also made of fieldstone. They are arches. Yes. Bear in mind, the window part in the arch is the same as any basement window, if indeed the wall goes into the basement. If this had been a normal wood-framed porch, those are just basement windows.

Comment: Yes, the basement windows go to the outside, of course. I'm saying that we cannot tell very well if in that picture the porch façade is part of a basement wall or if it isn't. It could be or not. It might just be a design feature.

Comment: Well, how about the bad guys leaving knives on the stairs inside the house? :) But I was too little to be told that at the time.

Comment: @Lambie It would be very unusual for a basement to be under a porch unless someone did some really crazy renovations. A porch typically has a skirt independent of the home’s foundation. I did see a house that closed in an outdoor basement entrance that might qualify when we were house shopping, so it could happen. We also saw a house that was such a maze of add-on rooms I was worried we’d end up in Narnia or something if we weren’t careful lol

Comment: I'd call it a scupper.

Comment: Actually, looking closer at the picture I think @PhilSweet has it right. The holes are in the rail, not in the apron.

Comment: It looks to me like the frontmost stone wall holds a bed raised about a foot off the ground and that those arches won't allow access or ventilation under the porch. You can see the ground level near the tree on the left side of the photo. Agree that what you describe is pretty common, but this particular instance looks decorative.

Comment: Looking at the drawings of the link you provided.  I think scupper might be the answer here.  Thanks for the research everyone.  Fun word, too!

Comment: @ColleenV You misread me. Anyway, these are not holes; they are openings in the form of arches. There is no railing at all. As for scuppers, those are usually found on **boats** but the term is usually used for a thingie on the roof that draws the water off a roof.